# Touchscreen on dell laptop suddenly stopped working

Tags: touchscreen

I have a dell inspiron 7000 with Ubuntu 18.04.3 and the touchscreen suddenly stopped working. Usually when this happens it starts responding again after being rebooted, but that hasn’t worked this time.